# Solution to non linear ODE $axy''+bxy'+cy+d\frac{y'}{y}=e+fx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know if there is any known solution to the ODE below?

$$axy''+bxy'+cy+d\frac{y'}{y}=e+fx$$

where a,b,c,d,e,f are constants.

I really want to avoid going numerical, but I could not find any solution avaliable. References are welcome, even if it does not address this equation specifically.

Comment: Law of reciprocity: "The amount of attention a question receives is proportional to the square of the amount of effort put into writing the question"

Comment: I don't see how I could add any other information relevant and useful to my question. I am asking if someone is aware of a existing solution to a differential equation, plain and simple. I wrote down that equation in a way everyone can understand, what else could I do?

Comment: You show your work in attempt to solve the problem. It might also be good to post a link showing that this type of problem, or a problem similar to the above, indeed has a solution, so that we don't waste our time.

Comment: I did not work to solve the ODE, that is the whole point of asking this question: knowing if the equation has been solved before, so that I can use the solution (without having to prove it myself). Maybe this (or some similar ODE) is some common equation in some area that I am not familiar with (e.g. physics) and I can build upon others work. I don't see what is the problem with that.

Comment: Nothing except that the Law of reciprocity applies...